# Is there a way to pause or control an animated gif in my browser?

Tags: animation, firefox

I'm in Firefox and I'm looking at a page which has several how-to sections.  Each of these has an animated git showing a user following the instructions.
The animation goes by too fast for me to be useful.  I just want a way to pause the animation so that I can zoom in and see the details better.  Then resume the animation.

I tried clicking on the GIF, and I get just the GIF, but it still is animated and I can't control it.

What I'd like is some way to have FF open the image so that I can pause and resume the image.  Some reliable FF extension or plug-inAn would be best.  An item in the context menu would be nice (using about:config).  Or an item in the Settings/Applications list for images in general, or .gif files in particular (also using about:config).  Or some application where I can open the app and drag the image from FF into the open app's window.

What I've tried is:

1. Changing how FF processes the click on the image.  Its Settings does not show anything related to images in the Applications section.  I can't find a way to configure FF to add more file types to this section.  *Anybody know how to do this?*
2. I can view the image in WMP (Windows Media Player), but this is a clumsy process.  First, I have to save the image somewhere, then I have to open the folder where I saved it, then do an Open With....  Then since WMP isn't on the list of apps, I have to do Select Another App, and scroll down to WMP and select that.  I don't want to make this the default for all GIF files, so I have to do this for each animated GIF.
   Once I've done this, WMP comes up and I can do what I want.
3. I tried a drag and drop from my image in FF to an open WMP window, but there's no response there.
4. I tried RealPlayer.  I can do an Open With and RealPlayer is on the list of apps.  But RealPlayer shows the image without animating it.  RealPlayer also has an Open command and I paste in the URL of the image, but it's the same result.
5. I loaded the Toggle Animated Gif extension for FF.  This is not satisfactory because I can either run the animation or show the GIF without any animation.  I want to be able to freeze the animation in the middle of it.

Answer (score 1):

Same difficulty here. Unfortunately, there's no such Firefox extension for now. The closest one is https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gifpuase. It allows to pause a GIT, but not to resume - so not enough for you.

While I also prefer Firefox, but for this I suggest Chrome and Gif Scrubber: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gif-scrubber/gbdacbnhlfdlllckelpdkgeklfjfgcmp. Not immediate, but powerful.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Gif Scrubber! (What I mean is, it solves a problem for me and I've happily installed it.)